# У ссылок появляется подчеркивание

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Когда зажимаю ссылку и отвожу курсор (не перехожу по ссылке), появляется не нужное подчеркивание и меняется цвет ссылки, после этого если нажать в произвольном месте ссылка возвращает прежний облик.  Класс hover и active проблему не решил.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без работающего примера с собственно CSS вряд ли чем-то поможем

Answer (score 2):

Вашу проблему **hover** и **active** должны решать. Если они не работают, то вы скорее всего не так  их определили в css-файле. Вы точно не забыли, что это не обычные классы, а ПСЕВДОклассы? Класс задаёте Вы сами через атрибут class. ПСЕВДОклассы уже вшиты в систему, их определять не надо. И у них отличается не только название, но и синтаксис. Обычные классы в css-файле описывают так: a.myclass {...}. Псевдоклассы пишут не через точку, а через двоеточие: a:active, a:hover. Это только предположение. Чтобы сказать точно надо бы посмотреть на Ваш код.

Answer (score 1):

```
a { text-decoration: none;}
```

удаляет с ссылок подчеркивание совсем

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте данный код

```
a, a:hover, a:active, a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black; /* устанавливаем нужный цвет */
}
```